# C#.net String to Int

Tags: c#, .net, string, int

I got an string like "404, Error". and I was wondering if there's some way to get just the integer part.

It's always about 3 chars, like 402, 403, 404 etc... So I could get just the 3 firsts characters, but I was wondering if there's some function in order to get the integer part from one string, like in php.

Comment: You could use a split on `,` and take the first part, assuming the format is always the same. What have you tried, though?

Comment: I'm trying to get the responses code from an api, but there's not method to get just the integer response, just the string "404, Forbidden" or "Forbidden", I'd like to get "404" instead of those ones. (Sorry for my english).

Comment: var errorCode = ("404, Error".Split(","))[0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP conversion function converts the leading characters and ignores the rest. You could do something similar in C# by extracting the leading digits with [`Regex.Match`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx) then calling [`Int32.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert the substring into an `int`:

```
    String s = Regex.Match("404, Error", @"^\d+").Value;
    Console.WriteLine(Int32.Parse(s));
    // 404
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you :)

Maybe I should use split instead of this one? I mean, there's a pattern so, I guess this one consumes more memory or it's slower.